# Is there any way to classify/ remove words (Exm. "Which", "potential", this, "are" etc.) using python from a list

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am currently working on project related to natural language processing and text mining i have write down a code to calculate the frequency of unique words in a text file.

```
Frequencey of:  trypanosomiasis --> 0.0029
Frequencey of:  deadly --> 0.0029
Frequencey of:  yellow --> 0.0029
Frequencey of:  humanassociated --> 0.0029
Frequencey of:  successful --> 0.0029
Frequencey of:  potential --> 0.0058
Frequencey of:  which --> 0.0029
Frequencey of:  cholera --> 0.01449
Frequencey of:  antimicrobial --> 0.0029
Frequencey of:  hostdirected --> 0.0029
Frequencey of:  cameroon --> 0.0029
```

Is there any library or method that can remove common words, adjectives helping verbs etc. (Exm. "Which", "potential", this, "are" etc.) from a text file so that I can explore the or calculate the most likely occurrence of scientific terminology into a text data.

Comment: are the words to be removed known? Are the words of interest known? And do you have a "codable" criterion for "scientific terminology"?

Comment: "are the words to be removed known ?" answer is yes as i posted common words like adjectives, helping verbs, etc.   "Are the words of interest known?" answer is not 100% known but yes i can give a set of words around 2000 rather defining criteria of known scientific words. My objective is to minimise the data set. because i have to explore abstracts of around 50k research articles. thanks

Comment: "Known" in a programming context means, do you have a list of such words or a way to decide if word X is among the ones you want to remove? If these "criteria" can do that, or if you actually do have a list, then edit your question to explain what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Usually in text analysis you remove stopwords - common words that hold little meaning about the text. These you can remove using nltk's stopwords (from https://pythonspot.com/en/nltk-stop-words/):

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

data = "All work and no play makes jack dull boy. All work and no play makes jack a dull boy."
stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
words = word_tokenize(data)
wordsFiltered = []

for w in words:
    if w not in stopWords:
        wordsFiltered.append(w)

print(wordsFiltered)
```

If there are additional words you want to remove, you can just add them to the set `stopWords`

Comment: thank for your valuable suggestion I already used this function of NLTK but result was not very helpful in my case and hence i came here. Thanks.